# How to run .exe file on many computers on the network at same time?

Tags: windows

I have an exe file and I want to run it every week on nearly 100 machines in the domain so it is difficult to open each computer and run the file every week.

I searched about deploy software through Group Policy but it will need a .msi file which I don't have.
so I thought about scheduled task but it will required to open each machine also and create a scheduled task. I also thought about doing a batch file contains command to run the exe file and run this bat through logon script from GPO but it will run every time machine turned on and I want it just to run every week.

Does anyone have any idea about how to solve it without having to logon to each computer and run the exe file with myself?

Comment: There are so many ways to do what you are asking....  Psexec, Powershell Remoting, etc.  I kinda worry that you haven't spend enough time actually doing your homework here.  `I thought about scheduled task but ` - You can create scheduled tasks with a Group Policy.

Answer (score 5):

There are a lot of third party options that do this.  Some of them include [LANDesk](http://www.landesk.com/), [Altiris Deployment Solution](http://www.symantec.com/deployment-solution/), etc.  There's also, as Zoredache pointed out in the comments, [PSexec](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897553.aspx), [powershell remoting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff700227.aspx), [using powershell to create a scheduled task](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2015/01/13/use-powershell-to-create-scheduled-tasks.aspx), and [scheduling a task via Group Policy](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725745.aspx).

(My point being that you have a *lot* of options.)

It would help narrow things down if you considered your budget, what version of Powershell is installed on the workstations, whether your domain controller is 2008 R2 or above, etc.